# Set a HashMap to null or to a new HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

In my project I have a few HashMaps that I will reuse frequently, I have been informed that HashMaps can cause memory leaks and that Map#clear is not very effective and that I should set my HashMap to null, however, I think putting a null check before every use of the HashMap looks ugly, so would setting the HashMap to Maps#newHashMap accomplish the same goal, or should I set it to null and perform a null check before every use?

Comment: "I have been informed that HashMaps can cause memory leaks and that Map#clear is not very effective and that I should set my HashMap to null" I never heard `HashMaps` specifically to have this problem. Anyway setting them to `null` just ensures that you *will* forget to check it for a certain code path and end up with a NPE. Is it really necessary for you to reuse them?

Comment: Why are you reusing maps? This is not typical practice. (And ignore whoever told you that `clear()` is "not effective".)

Comment: The HashMap is basically a passenger list, with a passenger as the key and the value being their destination, I could store this directly to the passenger through another method, but I can't add it directly to it's class as it's from an api. Should I look for some other type of data storage? Can someone explain to me why it's bad to reuse Maps?

Comment: Why would you want to throw away all the passengers together? A `remove` operation that removes one or more passengers seems a reasonable choice.

Comment: @user7 Maps#remove or the = null is being called after a forEach, so it should basically be the same, right?

Comment: I cannot comment much without getting the context. Say if the map is an instance variable, if the map is no longer needed, then you could consider creating a new object that holds the map.

Comment: @user7 It's a `public static` object, if you need more context just ask, I have a git repo but there are only two uses of the `Map` in the entire 16k+ line project, so I think it would be stupid to link it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw away all the entries in the map at a certain point of time, calling `clear` will remove all the entries. This is `O(n)` because it has to remove all the entries from the map.

The only reason (as far as I can imagine) to set it to null is to remove the references to the contents of the map. This will cause garbage collection to collect the objects in the map if there are no other active references to them.

But if the map is being used, initializing it with an empty map is the best thing to do as it will achieve the same purpose.

Comment: clear would make sense if other objects hold a reference to the map and might access it (though with a normal HashMap that obviously has some concurrency issue risks). Other than that, yeah, just go for  a new map.

Comment: @FrankHopkins It doesn't matter if the objects hold a reference to the map. I would clear/get rid of them anyway. If the map is the only referrer they would be eventually GC'ed.

Comment: no what I mean is that multiple 'things', say handlers, know the same map and operate both on the map's content. I.e. a UserHandler maintains the map but shares access to it with, say a PlaneHandler. In most cases you want to avoid something like that, but it might occur and make sense in some scenarios.